# Output printf Statement to .txt File C

Tags: c, bash, fwrite

Does anyone know how i can output what i get from this program, which is

"mydrive.img File Size in Blocks = 4096" and append that to a .txt file?

I need to do it in a similar way to what would be done in bash like " >> output.txt" but i need to do it in C

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  struct stat fi;
  stat("mydrive.img", &fi);
  printf("mydrive.img File Size in Blocks = %d\n", fi.st_blksize);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `yourprogram >> output.txt` works exactly the same. Else, just add more code to open, write, and close.

Comment: Just `fopen` the text file in mode `"at"` to append to a text file.

Comment: Not directly related, but you should check if `stat` succeeds.

Comment: I'm am often curious what is the proper format specifier to use with members like `blksize_t st_blksize`.  Various compilers define `blksize_t` as some _signed_ integer, but who knows what width?  Suggest using `printf("Size = %lld\n", (long long) fi.st_blksize);` to avoid a mis-match.

Answer (score 2):

```
FILE *f = fopen("filename.txt", "a");
if(f)
{
    fprintf(f, "mydrive.img File Size in Blocks = %d\n", fi.st_blksize);
    fclose(f);
}
else printf("Unable to open the target file\n");
```

EDIT: Updated code to check the return value of fopen as suggested by comment.

Comment: ... and don't forget to check if `fopen` returns `NULL`.

Comment: How do you do that? @Michael Walz